# oauth not returning authorization code

Tags: oauth

When trying to login with oauth the Salesforce server just calls my redirect uri with an empty querystring.

The login string:

`https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=*redacted*&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fsdomain.com%2Fapi%2Fpowerups%2Fsalesforce%2Fsettings%2Fcallback&scope=full%20refresh_token%20offline_access`

Enabled scopes:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: The scopes you have selected do not match the scopes in your login URL. Think that might be the problem? You don't really need all of those, I think. I built a simple app some time ago that just updates a record on Salesforce on behalf of the user, and its scopes were just `refresh_token`, `api` and `web`.

Comment: Strange thing it was working fine on my local with the exact same scopes

Comment: Problem was that we were using a subdomain as a redirect uri. For some reason SF decided not to send the code in that case

Comment: Good to know that you figured it out on your own. Mind adding a description of your solution as an answer to your question, for future references?

Comment: Added it. I was hesitant to do that because my answer is more of a comment

Comment: People here and their downvoting. Ugh.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was the use of a subdomain as the redirect uri.

For some reason SF decided not to send the code in the query string in that case.

I ended up solving it with a redirect. Which caused SF to send the request twice. The second time without the code. So I had to handle that as well.